# Concatenate string with real table SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, concatenation

Everyone 
I have this Query in SQL SERVER

```
declare @nivel AS INT

set @nivel =3

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 AS A inner join TABLE2 as B ON A.COL1 = b.COL + @NIVEL
```

I want concatenate a variable to have
 **A.COL1 = b.COL3**
WITHOUT convert all query in '' STRING

Comment: Table1 as b and Table2 as B?

Comment: What are datatype of A.Col1 and b.Col?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select * 
  from Table1 a
       join Table2 b on a.Col1=case @nivel
                                   when 1 then b.Col1
                                   when 2 then b.Col2
                                   when 3 then b.Col3
                                   ...
                                 end
```

however, this is extremely bad design. You should consider redesigning your `Table2` to contain something like

```
| ColNo | ColumnData
|   1   | Data of column 1
|   2   | Data of column 2
|   3   | Data of column 3
```

then your query will be more straightforward

```
select * 
  from Table1 a
       join Table2 b
         on a.Col1 = b.ColumnData 
        and b.ColNo = @nivel
```

Comment: YES IS A BAD DESIGN BUT CAN'T MODIFY

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
declare @nivel AS INT

set @nivel =3

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 AS A 
inner join TABLE2 as B ON A.COL1 = b.COL + CAST(@NIVEL AS CHAR)
```

Comment: INVALID COLUMN NAME B.COL

Comment: Write your actual column name.

Comment: It will not work anyway. `A.Col1` will be whatever is in the column `B.COL` concatenated with a number. But the question was how to compare to different columns (col1,col2,col3...) based on an index `@nivel`. Something like an index into an array.